# scala- dataset- how to use a function on two case classes?

Tags: case-class

I have two datasets and create two case classes (The reason why I don't join ds together is because I want to return the first matching record in ds B with key in ds A)

Below is my attempt so far. How can I map that function to two case classes? Many thanks! I'm quite new here.

```
case class a_class (idA: Int, numA: Int)
case class b_class(idB: Int, numB:Int )
def findNum(a:a_Class, b:b_class): Int = {
     if (a.idA =!=b.idB){
            break
       }else{
       return  b.numB
       }
 }
aTb.createOrReplaceTempView("tableA") 
bTb.createOrReplaceTempView("tableB")
var aDS = sqlContext.table("tableA").as[a_class]
var bDS = sqlContext.table("pview").as[b_class]
 //a_class.map(, => )).show //how do I use findNum function here?
```

Example input:

```
 +------+---+
 |idA  |numA|
 +------+---+
 |    a |100|
 |    b |200|
 +------+---+

 +------+---+
 |idB   |numB|
 +------+---+
 |a     |500|
 |a     |600|
 +------+---+
```

So the expected output is 500, as the first row is the first matching record in table B

Comment: can you update with sample input and expected output?

Comment: @user4046073 What do you mean by `The reason why I don't join ds together is because I want to return the first matching record in ds B with key in ds A`. In Spark `DataFrame/Dataset` is distributed. There is no first or last in Spark.

Comment: @himanshuIIITian _"There is no first or last in Spark"_ <-- unless you do aggregation or ordering.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski That's correct! My point was that @user4046073 wants to perform the operation using without `join`, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your solution lies in `join`, `groupBy` and `aggregation`

First your `case class` and the sample input data are mismatching as `a` and `b` cannot be `int` type. So `case classes` should be

```
case class a_class (idA: String, numA: Int)
case class b_class(idB: String, numB:Int )
```

Using these `case classes` you can create `dataSets`. For testing purposes I am creating as following

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val tableA = Seq(
  a_class("a", 100),
  a_class("b", 200)
).toDS

val tableB = Seq(
  b_class("a", 500),
  b_class("a", 600)
).toDS
```

Then the final `dataset` can be achieved using following method.

```
tableA.join(tableB, $"idA" === $"idB", "inner") // inner join of two datasets
  .drop("idA", "numA")   //droping columns of tableB
  .groupBy("idB")        //grouping data to get the first of each group
  .agg(first("numB").as("numB"))    //taking the first of each group
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+----+
|idB|numB|
+---+----+
|a  |600 |
+---+----+
```

**Updated**

Above result doesn't match with your desired output, this is because `join` reorders the `tableB`.

you can get your desired output by just doing

```
tableB.groupBy("idB")
  .agg(first("numB").as("numB"))
  .show(false)
```

the result will be first `row` of each `id` of `tableB`

```
+---+----+
|idB|numB|
+---+----+
|a  |500 |
+---+----+
```

If you want only the first `rows` with `id` that matches with `tableA` then you `join` with `tableA` as above and if you don't want data of `tableA` then you `drop` them as

```
val tempTableB = tableB.groupBy("idB")
  .agg(first("numB").as("numB"))

tableA.join(tempTableB, $"idA" === $"idB", "inner")
  .drop("idA", "numA")
  .show(false)
```

the output is first `row` of `tableB` that matches with `id` of `tableA`

```
+---+----+
|idB|numB|
+---+----+
|a  |500 |
+---+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer:) It definitely gives me some ideas. But the expected output is "a", "500", which is the first matching record from dataset B. Why drop columns of B after the join?

Comment: see my updated answer :) I hope i answered and solved your issues.

Comment: I kept both so that it will help others as well. :) Thanks for the acceptance and an upvote :)

Comment: when I tried to Join tempTableB with A, I got an error, as  tempTableB now is not a dataset but a Unit. Do you know how to fix this...?

Comment: how did you created tempTableB?

Comment: Just like you did, and when I tried to join, it says" error: value col is not a member of Unit". tempTableB is somehow not a dataset or table..?

Comment: Can you post another question with more detailed informations like how you create tempTableB and provide more error logs? so that me or somebody else can help you with that. :)

Comment: Thanks. I removed the .show after `tempTableB `, and error is gone somehow.... I don't understand why though..

Comment: show is an action. And since you haven't applied action in tempTableB nothing will be done. Transformations are applied when an action is done. So it seemed that the error is gone but as soon as you will do an action the error will reappear. So if you want to solve it, either you update this question or ask another one with as much detail as you can provide. :)

Comment: I see! But I was able to join tempTableB back to tableA and perform `show` to the final joint table and get the result. Would there still be an issue?

Comment: Without seeing the code and procedure it would be very difficult to reach to the conclusion. :) thats why I am asking you to ask another question with full detail so that we can help you understand whats wrong. :)

Comment: I post a new question along with the error message here, along with a link to this question:)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322005/spark-scala-show-action-appeared-to-have-changed-a-dataset-to-some-other-ty